Usage of ったら as a particle
What is the difference in nuance when using ったら in place of particles like は? (I assume that is what's going on in the following sentences)
For example:

それに、ヴァルー様ったら
リンクさんのこと、勇者だっていってますよ


もぉ　この街ったらやんなっちゃう！


まあ〜　ヤドルフさんたら
乱暴なんだから！
(There's no っ here, but I believe it's the same)


驚き・いらだちなどの気持ちを表す。「まあ、あなたっ—」
